# What is Pratyaksha PramANa to be precise?

Tags: pramana

Can anyone tell what is pratyaksha pramANa? What does it include? Only 5 sense organs or even intellect or mind also? Can apprehension power be termed as Direct Perception aka Pratyaksha pramANa?

Comment: @Rickross Can you give me more comprehensive answer?

Comment: @@Rohit Well i was not quite clear in my previous comment (so deleting it now)..... What i meant was that what the Yogis perceive at exalted states of consciousness is also pratyaksha for them.. Also as regards mind, it is one of the Indriyas.. There are 10 indriyas, mind is the 11th one.....

Comment: @Rickross 1+1 = 2 is Pratyaksha or not? Because it seems Pratyaksha to me

Comment: @@Rohit 1+1=2 is a mathematical proposition to be precise and not a proof. It can be proven only within an axiomatic mathematical system.. So, i am not getting ur point actually

Comment: @Rickross Okay, I am a bit confused.  But Mind apprehends 1+1 = 2 then why it is not Pratyaksha?

Comment: @Turiyanāth 1+1=2 is inference.

Comment: @Turiyanāth Pratyaksha is defined as contact of the sense organs with the sense objects. Pratyaksha also includes the mind sensing things since the mind is a sense organ. For example, the mind senses feelings like anger, pain, pleasure, etc. Yogic perception like siddhis also falls under Pratyaksha.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are different types of pramana like anumana, upamana,sabdha, pratyaksha e.t.c. All these different pramana will help you gain knowledge.

Pratyaksha pramana is a one form of knowledge (or rather source of knowledge) which can be gathered through perception.

Pratyaksha means direct, live (e.g. live cricket match). Pramana means proof. Your sense organ is the most important part in pratyaksha pramana because anything you touch or taste or hear will be perceived by your senses and that is how you will gain knowledge about that particular object or thing. These are external perception. 
However, everytime you perceive something your mind is what makes a distinction. Without your mind you perception won't make much of a difference. So, senses and mind both are included in this pramana

Sometime, this perception may give you false results. 
Let's say at night time you see a small piece of rope and compare it with a snake.